# "Если предположить, что..." - почему инфинитив?

Tags: синтаксис, глаголы

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему инфинитив?

> *Если **предположить**, что она уже покинула отель, то ...*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Инфинитивные предложения** ― это вид безличных предложений, которые часто используются в различных (простых и сложных) предложениях, например: Пропустить его! Здесь не проехать. Как бы не простудиться! Хотя субъект действия в инфинитивных предложениях не указывается, его можно определить из контекста.

В частности инфинитив может использоваться **в придаточных условия (ирреальных и реальных):**

(1)  Если бы с ним **поговорить** (= если бы мы с ним поговорили),  он, вероятно,  изменился бы в лучшую сторону.

(2) Если **предположить** (= если мы предположим), что она уже покинула отель, то найти ее будет сложно. 
Семантика таких предложений связана с **логическим обоснованием**: в придаточной части содержится основание, а в главной ― умозаключение, вывод.

Comment: Arina: cпасибо большое за ответ! мне попадает на глаза что Вы в предложении (2) используете индикатив. мне интере́сно почему Вы не используете сослагательное наклонение? в моем языке мы никогда не выражаем через индикатив то что не знаем с 100% уверенностью, поэтому я имею трудности в понимании этого. можно сказать что предположительность/ирреальность содержания придаточного предложения уже содержится в семантике глагола "предположить"? и что обе конструкции с разными наклонениями синонимы и поэтому говорящий делает предпочтение на индикатив?

Comment: У глагола "предположить" особая семантика, поэтому  в этом предложении не требуется сослагательное наклонение -  речь не идет о знании со 100% уверенностью.  Но попробуем использовать глагол "знать", и мы будем имеет сослагательное наклонение: Если бы точно знать, что она уже покинула отель, мы бы начали активные поиски в других местах. И об инфинитиве: инфинитив используется в безличном предложении, когда не требуется указания на конкретное лицо, это более краткая и удобная форма. Но инфинитив может выражать реальную или ирреальную ситуацию, достаточно добавить частицу БЫ.

Comment: Arina: извините, еще один вопрос: проверьте меня, пожалуйста - если переформулировать предложение в "предположим, она уже покинула отель" -> это БСП, в котором "предположим" - императив, так?

Comment: Предположим - это форма индикатива (императив: предположите), и запятая в БСП при изъяснительных отношениях не ставится (ставится тире или двоеточие). Поэтому "предположим" - это вводное предложение. Реально это может звучать так: Допустим (= предположим), она уже покинула отель, тогда каковы будут наши действия?

Comment: поняла! : ) вижу мою ошибку: я ставила "даваите" перед "предположим" и думала что это императив. спасибо Вам большое за помощь и объяснение! really appreciate it!

Comment: извините, пожалуйста, что возвращаюсь. 
"Если предположить, что она уже покинула отель, то мы уже не сможем ей помочь." - стараюсь определить синтаксическую функцию части "что она уже покинула отель" и если правильно это делаю, то это изъяснительное. согласно книгам "если" указывает на условие; но "мы не сможем ей помочь, если предположим, что..."??? не очень похоже на придаточное условия... помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Предложение можно упростить:  Если она уже покинула отель, то мы  не сможем ей помочь. Это СПП с придаточным условия.  Но это одна из гипотез, можно предположить, что она еще в отеле, и сделать другой вывод. Здесь придаточное условия включает изъяснительную часть (первое и второе предложение), а главным является третье предложение.